# how to preload posts like instagram feed

Tags: android-recyclerview, instagram, smooth-scrolling, nested-resources

Im using recyclerview in my app but the problem with it, is it looks not so good as if we scroll the images or videos take time and the viewholder stretches. What i want to do is load the upcoming posts before user gets to them and if user scrolls too fast then they must have to occupy the height of image or video which is being shown there like instagram or youtube. links for the articles or the code snippets will be very helpful thanks in advance!
(If i could not explain well or the problem is not cleared please try scrolling insta or youtube you will get it)

Comment: have you tried Infinite Scroll

Comment: You are looking for Pagination in Android

Comment: @C.K yes i tried but that doesnot load feed before it is visible

Comment: @Sharan i already have pagination in my app, i want to load paginated posts simultaneously like listview does